# basic stored procedure (update column value)

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have a basic table that looks like the following:

```
SQL> desc comments
Name              Null?        Type
---------------------------------------
COMMENT_ID        NOT NULL     NUMBER
POST_ID           NOT NULL     NUMBER
USER_ID           NOT NULL     NUMBER
MESSAGE           NOT NULL     VARCHAR2(2500)
MESSAGE_TIME      NOT NULL     TIMESTAMP(6)
UPVOTES           NOT NULL     NUMBER
```

What I'd like to do is have a stored procedure be called that would increment the upvotes.  This seems to make the most sense because I don't want to pass in anything other than the comment_id and post_id.

I think I should be doing something like this (please excuse syntax, I haven't messed with stored procedures in a long long time)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure proc_upvote_comment (comment_id NUMBER , post_id NUMBER) 
BEGIN
    SELECT UPVOTES FROM COMMENTS 
        WHERE COMMENTS.COMMENT_ID  = proc_upvote_comment.comment_id 
              AND COMMENTS.POST_ID = proc_upvote_comment.post_id;
   //Call an update
END;
/
```

But I just don't seem to know the missing piece here.  I've tried looking at 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#i1007682
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6009.htm

And a few other places on the site - but I'm just missing something.

Any help in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason this is not working for you:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE procedure proc_upvote_comment (comment_id NUMBER , post_id NUMBER) 
 AS
 BEGIN
    UPDATE COMMENTS 
       SET UPVOTES = UPVOTES + 1
     WHERE COMMENTS.COMMENT_ID  = proc_upvote_comment.comment_id 
          AND COMMENTS.POST_ID = proc_upvote_comment.post_id;
 END;
```

Remember that SQL works with sets ;)

Comment: Every time I do that i get the error
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:
; is with authid as cluster order using external deterministic parallel_enabled pipelined.  The symbol "is" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue

Comment: @PSU_Kardi - You need an `AS` before the `BEGIN` (or an `IS`, either would work)

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure proc_upvote_comment (p_comment_id NUMBER , p_post_id NUMBER) 
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE comments
     SET upvotes = upvotes + 1
   WHERE comment_id = p_comment_id
     AND post_id    = p_post_id;
END;
/
```

Generally, you want to have a naming convention to differentiate parameters from column names.  I prefer using the `p_` prefix for parameters and the `l_` prefix for local variables but there are other conventions.  If you don't do this and you use the same name for a column and for a parameter, the SQL statement will resolve identifiers first using the name of the column and then using the name of the parameter.  Resorting to prefixing the name of the stored procedure to provide scope resolution works but it's rather cumbersome.